# How to find permutation importance using sparse matrix X?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix X (`csr_matrix`), since a dense version does not fit into RAM.

I want to find permutation importance for my estimator using the sparse matrix X.

When I run the following code, I receive an error `TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required.`

This code replicates the error:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
   'y': [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  'categ': ['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'ant', 'fox', 'seal'],
  'size': ['big', 'small', 'big', 'tiny', 'medium', 'big']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

X = df[['categ', 'size']]
y = df['y']

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=True)
X = encoder.fit_transform(X)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logit = LogisticRegression()
logit.fit(X, y)

# This step throws an error
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance
perm = permutation_importance(logit, X, y)
```

**Is there another way to find permutation importance without making X dense?**

I am using python 3.9.16 and sk-learn 1.2.2.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried `X = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(X)`  after `X = encoder.fit_transform(X)` ?

Comment: @HMH1013 This is working, thank you! It appears the pandas sparse Dataframe is slightly smaller than the `csr_matrix` with my original data. Would you mind posting this as a complete answer or should I? Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ Dudelstein Thanks for inviting for posting the answer.

Here is doc for [permutation_importance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance.html), we can find out the input `X` accept `ndarray or DataFrame`. If we have a very large sparse matrix does not fit into RAM, we can convert the sparse matrix to `pandas dataframe` with the function `pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix`.

This will pass a sparse array to `pd.series`, then to `pd.dataframe` without converting the sparse array to dense.

Here is an example with creating a sparse array of with a shape `(50000, 2500000)` and 9999585 stored elements:

```
import scipy.sparse as sps
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

rows, cols = 250*200, int(2.5*1e6)
# Initialization
arr_sparse = csr_matrix((rows, cols))
# Fill values in the sparse matrix
for j in np.arange(10): 
    r = np.random.randint(rows, size=1000000)
    c = np.random.randint(cols, size=1000000)
    d = np.ones((1000000,))
    arr_sparse = arr_sparse + sps.coo_matrix((d, (r, c)), shape=(rows, cols))
```

If we try to convert `arr_sparse` to dense, it will give us an RAM error :

```
Unable to allocate 931. GiB for an array with shape (50000, 2500000) and data type float64
```

But if we convert `arr_sparse` to `pd.dataframe`, this will pass with 24.38s without throwing a RAM error.

Comment: To tie it back to my question, what's needed is to convert `X` to a sparse pandas DataFrame via `pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(X)` after `X` is transformed via the encoder.